# Command `\pause` help

Tags: beamer

```
                 \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      %-----

      \usepackage{empheq, nccmath} % empheq package loads mathtools
         \usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
           \usepackage{graphicx}
       \usepackage{color}
         \usetheme{Madrid}

     \begin{document}

         \begin{frame}{title}
      \pause
     \begin{block}{}   
      We have

                 \begin{equation*}
                r(\mathbf{T}):=\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{|\alpha|=n,\\\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^d}}\frac{n!}{\alpha!}{\mathbf{T}^*}^{\alpha}\mathbf{T}^{\alpha}\right\|^{\frac{1}{2n}}\pause=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{|\alpha|=n,\\\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^d}}\frac{n!}{\alpha!}{\mathbf{T}^*}^{\alpha}\mathbf{T}^{\alpha}\right\|^{\frac{1}{2n}}.
            \end{equation*}
           Here for $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_d) \in \mathbb{N}^d$, we used.
       \end{block}
           \end{frame}
         \end{document}
```

First I want to obtain

[image]

Then,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 \begin{frame}{}
   \begin{block}{}   
     We have
     \begin{equation*}
       r(\mathbf{T}):=\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}
       \left\|
         \displaystyle\sum_{\substack{|\alpha|=n,\\\alpha\in
             \mathbb{N}^d}}
         \frac{n!}{\alpha!}{\mathbf{T}^*}^{\alpha}\mathbf{T}^{\alpha}
       \right\|^{\frac{1}{2n}}
       \onslide<2>{
         =\lim_{n\to+\infty}
         \left\|
           \displaystyle\sum_{\substack{|\alpha|=n,\\\alpha\in
               \mathbb{N}^d}}
           \frac{n!}{\alpha!}{\mathbf{T}^*}^{\alpha}\mathbf{T}^{\alpha}
         \right\|^{\frac{1}{2n}}
       }.
     \end{equation*}
     Here for $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_d) \in
     \mathbb{N}^d$,
     we used.
   \end{block}
 \end{frame}
```

PS While I was writing it, @leandrils proposed another solution, with `\only` command.  If you are interested, there is a subtle difference between these solutions:
`\only` does not typeset a hidden text while
`\onslide` typesets and hides it,  leaving the space on the slides where the text is not present.

In your example `\only` typesets the first equation centered, and  on the second slide it moves it to the left.  On the other hand, `\onslide` typesets the first equation with the space for the second one.  Depending on your taste you might want either solution. Some people like each slide to have correctly centered equations, while other people dislike the surrounding text on slides "jumping" giving the way to newly inserted fragments.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You might want to point out that this approach will not horizontally center the expression on the first slide (as shown in the sketch in the question). Also, the code is not compilable as some `}`s seem to be missing.

Comment: Done - thanks for noticing

Comment: Thanks however juste if I add ` \begin{frame}{title}   \pause` I have the same problem. Please see my edit.

Comment: `\pause` is a very simple command intended for simple sequential uncovering of text.  If you need anything more complex, `\only` and `\onslide`  must be used instead.

Comment: If you want silde 1 with title only, slide 2 with the first equality, slide 3 with all text, use `\onslide<2-3>` and `\onslide<3>` correspondingly

Comment: If we have 6 slides? I try with `\onslide<2-3-4-5-6>` but it doen't works. Thanks.

Comment: the correct syntax is `<2-6>`.  An overlay specification is a list of comma separated entries setting spans like `<2-4,6-8>` which means "put texts on slides 2,3,4,6,7,8".  There are more advanced forms, like `<3->` which means "slide 3 and following" or `<-3,5,7->` which means "all slides up to and including 3, then slide 5, the alll slides starting from 7"

Answer (score 3):

Use `\only<2>` instead of `\pause`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{empheq, nccmath} % empheq package loads mathtools
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{}
     \begin{block}{}   
      We have
      \begin{equation*}
         r(\mathbf{T}):=\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}^*}\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{|\alpha|=n,\\\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^d}}\frac{n!}{\alpha!}{\mathbf{T}^*}^{\alpha}\mathbf{T}^{\alpha}\right\|^{\frac{1}{2n}}\only<2>{ =\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left\|\displaystyle\sum_{\substack{|\alpha|=n,\\\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^d}}\frac{n!}{\alpha!}{\mathbf{T}^*}^{\alpha}\mathbf{T}^{\alpha}\right\|^{\frac{1}{2n}}.}
       \end{equation*}
       Here for $\alpha = (\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_d) \in \mathbb{N}^d$, we used.
     \end{block}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]